# Format Map by looking at the first and last elements

Tags: java, hashmap

I am wanting to return a string as follows using the Map
"Cars: 1 value is $ 10.00, 2 value is R $ 20.00, 3 value is $ 5.00. Total = 25.00."

How do I assemble the structure as follows:

If the Map has 1 records, it displays the text as follows
"Cars: 1 value is $ 10.00.Total = 30.00."

If the Map has 2 records, it displays the text as follows
"Cars: 1 value is $ 10.00, 2 value is $ 20.00. Total = 30.00."

If the Map has more than 3 records, it displays the text as follows
"Cars: 1 value is $ 10.00, 2 value is $ 20.00, 3 value is $ 40.00. Total = 60.00."

Rule if the list has 2 elements, separate it with a comma and put a period at the end
If the list has an element it adds only a period at the end

I set up the map as follows

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> code = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>();
        code.put(1, new BigDecimal("10.0"));
        code.put(2, new BigDecimal("20.0"));
        code.put(3, new BigDecimal("5.99"));

for (Map.Entry<Integer, BigDecimal> entry : codeMap.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    BigDecimal value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(String.format("key: %s | value: %s", key, value));
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting here?

Comment: I'm not clear on what is displayed if the map has more than 3 values.  By the way, "Cars: 1 value is $ 10.00, 2 value is $ 20.00, 3 value is $ 40.00. Total = 70.00." for 3 cars.  Also, you could use a List<BigInteger> instead of a Map, if you're just using numbers to identify the car.

Comment: I can see a typo in the code also . In for loop , you are using codeMap , but you have declared Map as code. Please check .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringJoiner` to ease the joining process of individual results. See the below example code

```
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner( "," );
    double total = 0.0;
    for( Integer i : code.keySet() )
    {
        sj.add( i + " value is $ " + code.get( i ).floatValue() );
        total += code.get( i ).doubleValue();
    }
    StringBuilder sb;
    sb = new StringBuilder( "Cars " ).append( sj.toString() ).append( ". Total is $" ).append( total );

    System.out.println( sb.toString() );
```

This will provide the output

```
Cars 1 value is $ 10.0,2 value is $ 20.0,3 value is $ 5.99. Total is $35.99
```